# imagecreatefromweb causing FATAL error which cannot be caught

Tags: php

I have a simple block of code that when fed an invalid file should be able to provide some user feedback, but I am finding the call to imagecreatefromweb** simply stops all PHP processing with a "Fatal error:  gd-webp cannot get webp info in .." straight away.

I have tried to place this in a try catch but this doesn't make a difference.

How do I catch this error?

```
$fn="c:/temp/some_image.jpg";
try {
     echo "<LI>Loading $fn";
     $imgRes = imagecreatefromwebp($fn); // Should really be "@imagecreatefromwebp($fn)"
     echo "<LI>Loaded ok";
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<LI>Exception ".$e->getMessage();
}
echo "<LI>Finished";
```

I am using PHP7.3.12 via Windows.
(Note this code will work when fed a valid .webp file).

** (or imagecreatefromjpg or imagecreatefrompng, etc)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php Long story short, PHP's legacy of using errors rather than exceptions means you need to `catch (Error $e)`. Though I am having difficulty getting gd to throw an error with similar code rather than a warning.

Comment: I've tried both `catch (Error $e)` and `catch (Exception $e)` and neither prevent PHP from causing an unrecoverable error. I get a whitescreen and the error `Fatal error: Paletter image not supported by webp ...` regardless of how I try to catch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`exif_imagetype()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) to ensure the file is in WEBP format:

```php
<?php

    $fn="image.jpg";

    if (!file_exists($fn)) {
        echo 'File does not exists';
    } elseif (exif_imagetype($fn) === IMAGETYPE_WEBP) {
        $imgRes = imagecreatefromwebp($fn);
    } else {
        echo "Image is not in WEBP format";
    }
```

**Note:** use [`file_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to ensure the file is really there

Comment: Remember that the exif_imagetype requires the "exif" extension enabled in your php.ini, and by default it is not.